Скормить картинку тессеракту , не сохраняя ее
У меня есть такой метод для создания скриншота:
  Image CaptureScreen(int sourceX, int sourceY, int destX, int destY,
     Size regionSize)
 {
     Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(regionSize.Width, regionSize.Height);
     Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
     g.CopyFromScreen(sourceX, sourceY, destX, destY, regionSize);
     return bmp;
 }

В тессеракт его можно скормить, передав такой параметр: 
Библиотеку использую EmguCv.
Сначала я пробовал использовать этот код:
private bool CheckTable()
{
    using Tesseract tesseract = new Tesseract(@"C:\langs", "rus", OcrEngineMode.TesseractLstmCombined);
    Image<Bgr, byte> image = CaptureScreen(757, 476, 0, 0, size3).ToImage();
    tesseract.SetImage(image);
    tesseract.Recognize();
    string text = tesseract.GetUTF8Text().Replace("\r\n", ""); 
    bool result = text.Contains("Вы успешно") || text.Contains("не доступен");
    return result;
}

Но выдало такую ошибку:

Как еще можно скормить картинку тессеракту , не сохраняя ее?

пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

@aleksandrbarakin хорошо, просто я копировать не мог там ошибку

Image<Bgr, byte> image = new Image<Bgr, byte>(CaptureScreen(757, 476, 0, 0, size3)); вот так пробовали?

Ещё вариант - установить пакет https://www.nuget.org/packages/Emgu.CV.Bitmap/

@aepot , пробовал, выдавало ошибку что не может преобразовать Image в byte. Сейчас скачал библиотеку на Bitmap , и если использовать  Image<Bgr, byte> image = CaptureScreen(757, 476, 0, 0, size3).ToImage(); , то выдаст ошибку "
Ошибка CS0411 Аргументы типа для метода "BitmapExtension.ToImage<TColor, TDepth>(Bitmap)" не могут определяться по использованию. Попытайтесь явно определить аргументы типа."

Ну так вам написано явно, что нужно сделать .ToImage<Bgr, byte>()

@aepot сработало спасибо )
